# Puppet vcsrepo behind firewall?

Tags: git, github, puppet

Trying to use vcsrepo module from puppet to install a GIT repository for devstack. Using https://github.com/... But am behind a firewall. There is a proxy server available for http, https, and FTP access to the Internet.

Is there a way to include the proxy, when using this module?  I didn't find anything in the vcsrepo that seems to work. Willing to tweak (hack) the module, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could look in the module vcsrepo/lib/puppet/provider/vcsrepo/git.rb

near the bottom of the file at:

```
def git_with_identity(*args)
```

add the following just under the above line:

```
if @resource.value(:http_proxy)
    ENV['http_proxy'] = @resource.value(:http_proxy)
    ENV['https_proxy'] = @resource.value(:http_proxy)
end
```

Next edit vcsrepo/lib/puppet/type/vcsrepo.rb - before the last end add:

```
 newparam :http_proxy do
 desc "http proxy to use to communicate with the outside world"
end
```

Now in your puppet manifest you can add http_proxy var:

```
vcsrepo { '/var/www/blash':
            ensure => present,
            provider => git,
            http_proxy => 'http://prxy.local:8080',
            require => Class['git-core'],
            source => 'http://github.com/blah/blah.git';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around this without modifying the vcsrepo code.
Instead I created a .gitconfig file in root's home directory, which specify the proxy info for https/http protocols.